# Static linking in Dart FFI

Tags: dart, ffi

I am writing a cli on Dart using a third-party library in the C language. I want to compile a single executable file. Is it possible? I linked the library dynamically using ffi. But is there a way to do statically, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65047831/how-to-statically-link-c-code-with-dart-code-to-enable-ffi-with-the-dart-ffi-lib)  ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to statically link C code with Dart code to enable ffi with the dart ffi library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65047831/how-to-statically-link-c-code-with-dart-code-to-enable-ffi-with-the-dart-ffi-lib)

Comment: Not really. I don't understand how I should link the library when compiling. Those. which instructions to use.
If I use dynamic linking, I include the path to the library in the code `var myLib = DynamicLibrary.open(pathToMyLib)`
But if I use it `var myLib = DynamicLibrary.executable()`, how do I statically link the library at compile time?

Comment: It's the same question though. This is a duplicate.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dart compile exe` does not currently support linking in static libraries ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/47718)).

The best approach for now is to use `DynamicLibrary.open`, open a dynamic library relative to the executable, and ship a zip/folder with an executable and dynamic libraries as the final app.